# Multitenant Playframework 2.6 application in Scala with ReactiveMongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, multi-tenant, reactivemongo

I am developing a multi-tenant REST application with Playframework 2.6 and I am searching for a design that allows me to:

1. Extract tenantId from a route like .../tenants/:tenantId/...
2. Isolate @Singleton services that uses persistence layers
3. Handle multiple connection pools with reactivemongo (0.16.0-play26)

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What have you already tried/found by yourself?

Comment: Currently I tried to extract tenant identifiers with action composition but I have not any idea to handle multi-tenancy for isolating @Singleton services to read/write through different connection pools.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to implement it as follows:

1. An Tenant identifiers are extracted from the `X-Tenant-Id` HTTP request header;
2. Services expose all tenant-specific methods that requires the `Tenant` implicit parameter, this allows to take its connection pool;
3. I developed a class that handles all connection pools and store them into a mutable map.